# Mongodb $lookup aggregation returns all documents from foreign index

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have a users index

```
[{
 username: "foo@bar,
 roleIds: [ Types.ObjectId("1234") ]
},
{
 username: "foo@moo,
}]
```

With a `roles`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60465768f768621ec5828b68"),
    "name" : "admin",
    "permissionIds" : ObjectId("604657e8e715ss1f2d78b945")
}
```

and `permissions`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604657e8e715ss1f2d78b945"),
    "name" : "view-user",
}
```

When I get the user by username, I want to hydrate the role information. **Not all users have roleIds** so I need to be able to still return the user regardless of whether they have roleIds.

At the moment the lookup for the roles always returns every item in the `roles` index!

My idea is that I lookup the `roles` joining on the index `roles` by the array `roleIds` to `_ids`

Then I pipeline within that lookup to grab the permission information from within the role.

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            'username':'foo@bar',
          }
      },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'roles',
            let: {'roleIds': '_id'},
            as: 'roles',
            pipeline: [{
                $lookup: {
                  from: 'permissions',
                  let: {'permissionIds': "_id"},
                  as: 'permissions',
                  pipeline: [
                    {
                      $project: {
                        name: 1
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },{
                $project: {
                  name: 1,
                  permissions: 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ])
```

This route just seems to return **all** documents within the `roles` index regardless of whether it is actually a join.

Is there something I am immediately doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following things are wrong in your query:

1. You are passing wrong variables to `pipeline` inside `let` in both the lookups.
2. Missing `$match` stage inside pipeline which performs the actual join operation.
3. Initialize empty `roleIds` with `[]` using `ifNull` (since all users don't have that field).

Try this query:

```js
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'username': 'foo@bar',
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'roles',
            let: { 'roleIds': { $ifNull: ["$roleIds", []] } },
            as: 'roles',
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$roleIds"] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'permissions',
                        let: { 'permissionId': "$permissionIds" },
                        pipeline: [
                            {
                                $match: {
                                    $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$permissionId"] }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                $project: {
                                    name: 1
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        as: 'permissions'
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        name: 1,
                        permissions: 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]);
```